# Django rest and axios post

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, axios

So to I'm trying to submit data to my backend django rest. In my backend, If I manually type in the params like so

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comments/create/?type=post&slug=first-post

the data gets submitted and the comment gets created. I'm using react/redux as a my front end with axios and I've setup my request to submit data the same way. Passing in data, params, etc like so,

```
export const createComment = (comment) => {
return dispatch => {        
    return  axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comments/create/`,qs.stringify({
            content: comment.content
        }),
        {
            params: {
                type: comment.type,
                slug: comment.slug,
                parent_id: comment.parent_id
            }, 
            xsrfHeaderName: "X-CSRFToken",
        }
    ).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
    })
 }
}
```

This is the error I keep getting,

xhr.js:178 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comments/create/?type=post&slug=second-post 500 (Internal Server Error)

Can't understand how this continues to be a server error yet when I submit the comment through my django rest the comment successfully goes through. I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the client side `Error`, Copy paste from the server console the Server side `Error`

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part. My server errors weren't rendering onto the terminal and couldn't find the mistake. Fixed the output of the server errors to display on the terminal and found the error. The user instance wasn't being passed through which continued to give me this error. Fixed it now, thank you!

Comment: Cool. Happy Coding!